# Does Windows7 support symbolic links (folder 'shortcuts')?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I see W7 seems to have more support for virtual folders, that don't correspond to actual directories on the disk. Does it also support proper symbolic links so I can e.g create a symbolic link c:\temp\external which maps to d:\xyz\, so that c:\temp\external\file.txt is d:\xyz\file.text?
If so how do I create these?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes.

NTFS had the [feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) for some time, [junctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) have been available longer, and Vista was the first version of Windows with support, Windows 7 has improved it, apparently, but I'm not sure of the specifics off the top of my head.

From within an elevated (run as admin) `cmd` window you need to use the command `mklink`, usage is as such:

```
mklink <flag> link target
```

This creates `link` which points to `target`, both can be absolute or relative paths, `link` must not exist and obviously `target` must.

You can use the available flags to adjust the type of link created:

```
<no flag> - file symbolic link
/H        - file hard link
/D        - directory symbolic link
/J        - directory junction (hard link, essentially)
```

Comment: Ah, so it's only available from the command-line? Thanks.

Comment: @John, as far as I'm aware, yes, and only to admin users.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! I missed this feature in XP but they did add it in Widows 7. check out http://www.windows7home.net/how-to-create-symbolic-link-in-windows-7/