# exe file referencing windows symlinks

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I'm using an exe file that references other folders in the current directory, if I create a symlink to the parent folder everything works fine.

When I create individual symlinks for the child folders, I get errors... any idea why or any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Good /j (junction) suggestion seems to work well:
[Windows Symlink & working directory](https://superuser.com/questions/555804/windows-symlink-working-directory)

So then why would anyone ever create a normal symlink or /d?

Comment: Junctions cannot link to files and cannot be relative. See the table in https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html