# Is it possible to create global .lnk Windows' files?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, wildcards, syntax, mklink

I tried to research for this, but nothing was clear to me. I'm a true newbie when talking about coding, as it has been a while I don't work with it. All I've found was VB, and some weird hex registry entries fiddling on Windows' `.lnk` shortcuts.

What I'm trying to figure out: If it is possible to create global shortcut `.lnk` files (using wildcards or Regex), so that way I could make a portable app, place a shortcut on the upper directory, and zip it, hence the software which is within the folder among a bunch of files don't become a mess to find/run.

I found a few system variables which can be used to open on specific Windows directories (like `%ProgramFiles%`, `%WinDir%`, `%HomeDrive%`, `%HomePath%`, and etc), but nothing so reasonable. Also found some cmd commands in order to create them, but not so sure about symbolic and hard links (how to use them in syntax).

I've made a few `autorun.inf` and `.bat` files that opened sub-directories, but I couldn't figure out how to do it with .lnk files.

Then, in terms of dummies, is there an easy way to do that?

Thanks.

EDIT: Went a little further on my research and figured out that it's related directly to symbolic links and directory junctions. Found this thread, which gave me a few more informations:

[Windows Symlink & working directory](https://superuser.com/questions/555804/windows-symlink-working-directory?rq=1)

---

Here are some useful links from my research:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438204/create-a-windows-shortcut-lnk-in-go
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662550/can-a-global-shortcut-lnk-be-created-programmatically
3. [How to make a shortcut from CMD?](https://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd)
4. https://ss64.com/nt/shortcut.html
5. https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/151752-lnkeditorgui-windows-shortcut-lnk-link-editor-gui/
6. http://www.freebasic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14130
7. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?322799-Change-Shortcut-Properties-Icon

Comment: [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)

Comment: *%ProgramFiles%* isn't a wild card it's a system variable.  No; Windows doesn't have global shortcuts and *%ProgramFiles%* isn't a shortcut.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the correction, @Ramhound.

Comment: they're environment variables, not wildcard which is often `*`

Comment: Thanks guys, I just edited the post for the terrible mistakes. But the question still remains...

Comment: it seems you want to create a lnk file with relative path. Why don't just use a .bat or .cmd file? [How do I create a shortcut (.lnk) with a relative target?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3418541/995714)